# iPhone QRCode Generator n Decoder

Tags: iphone, ios, qr-code

I have to create an app in iPhone which can generate QRCode for Text,Mail,Map,Photos etc. And can also Decode the QRCode. Has anyboday have idea about its API or example?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120071/qr-code-library-for-iphone

Comment: The posts for [encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570678/qrcode-encoding-a-simple-string-in-ios) and [decoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166646/qr-code-scanning-in-ios-application) QR code may also give some idea regarding that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I usually use [QR Code Encoder](https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C) for QR generation and [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/) for decoding QR (It also works with other code standards)

They are very easy to use.

Comment: I am also looking for both...generation and Reading... Can you please share your code about how to integrate both in a single project...i am getting confused regarding this library and all...

Comment: @ender Does it scan and generate QR Code for images as well?

Comment: @Developer do you mean encoding the image itself? I usually encode the image URL. If you want to encode the image itself, try encoding it to a base64 string first.

Comment: @ender No, I mean when I scan the QR code, it should display the image as its displays the textual information. Please let me know if it is unclear to you. And please also let me know if it is possible or not. Thanks :-)

Comment: I know maybe it's too late for answering, but AFAIK you can't do that with those libraries, I think augmented reality would be a better approach for what you need.