# QRCode encoding a simple string in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, qr-code, encode

I have downloaded a sample code from [github](https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C) for QRCode encoding.

It works fine and generates an image with QRCode for string that I specified.

But, when I scan that image, it displays the string like `http://mystring`.

I need only `mystring`. How to do that? Is the problem is with QRscanner app?

I think the [QRencoderapp](https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C) is about encoding an url.

Is there any other sample to encode just a simple string (not url)?

or

Is there any changes to be done get the string instead of url in the above code?

Comment: It's possible that QRCode will generate a "http" + , for all you strings you send it. Try on http://qrcode.kaywa.com/ for example and compare if it's the same "image" representation. If it doesn't match, then do a regex.

Comment: you can just split the word with // in this app.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD, "in this app" means I can't understand, pls expand ur opinion

Comment: which you are download from github

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD, I don't know where to edit, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I 've solved my problem.

I downloaded a project from this [Github link](https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator).

The code in that prjct creates a QRCode image for a simple text.

```
NSString *code = @"Our String to be encoded";

Barcode *barcode = [[Barcode alloc] init];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[barcode setupQRCode:code];

ourImageView.image = barcode.qRBarcode;
```

Hope, this will help others.