# Scandit scanner SDK in IOS

Tags: ios, barcode, qr-code

Hey I'm new to iPhone and I have been trying to use `Scandit SDK`. I installed the `Community FREE SDK` from http://www.scandit.com/pricing/ for scanning QR Code images, and it's working fine on my application. I want to know that if i will deploy my app on Apple Store using `Scandit` then it will be problem in future because of Free SDK. Or for this, i need to purchase paid `Enterprise SDK` of $199 or $399. Please give me any suggestion.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the free version only

if you have more suggestion for `QR Code`, you need some idea follow this link [QR Code Scanning in ios application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166646/qr-code-scanning-in-ios-application)