# How to use QRCode Reader from cocos2d-x App?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-x, qr-code, zxing, zbar

I want to use the function of QRCodeReader in my app.
My app is developed in cocos2d-x.
I think I have to use native code (Android/iOS).
There are some ways to use QRCodeReader in iOS. (ZXing,ZBar,and the QR function in iOS (http://www.renaudpradenc.com/?p=453))

But my code in any way doesn't work well..
Anyone know how to do?

It might not related to this question, the following code can call Camera in iOS.

```
void NativeLauncher::ShowCameraView(){
    AppController  *appController = (AppController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [appController.viewController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: What is your actual problem with it? What does work, what doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great tutorial in Objective C:

[How To Scan QR Code Using AVFoundation Framework](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/)

and here's one in Swift:

[QR Code Swift tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-reader-swift/)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer.

You´ll probably think in 2 strategies, since there a no native cocos2d-x support for QRCode decoding.

**1) Develop Objective-C -> C++ wrapper**

Implement AVFoundationFramework methods in the objc side and also decoding helpers for images that you´ll use 
Call those methods on a C++ wrapper class in cocos2d-x project (check Carlo´s Google Game Services as start point: https://github.com/cpinan).

**2) Use any QRCode C++ Library**

There are many QRCode Decoders in c++, but you need to make sure that libraries  targeting archtectures that you need. (e.g https://github.com/zxing/zxing)

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If your App is for above iOS 7, you can use `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` to implement QRCode scan inside your App. If you don't know how to implement `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` here is a Simple implementation for you.

https://github.com/dilumnavanjana/MetaQR

Add MetaQR.h & .m files to your Project & Add this code,

```
MetaQR *metaQR = [[MetaQR alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
metaQR.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:metaQR];
```

This delegate method will gives you the data of the QRCode

```
-(void)capturedMetaOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Deployment Target of 7.0 or above, you can use AVFoundationFramework for reading the Qr code.

Here is a tutorial for doing this : http://www.ama-dev.com/iphone-qr-code-library-ios-7/

This question is also answered here : [QR Code Scanning in ios application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166646/qr-code-scanning-in-ios-application)